# Quarkus numeric type (Integer, Float) return 0 instead of null

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I used the PostgreSQL and Quarkus Panache.

The database contains null value for numeric columns.

After migrated to the 6th hibernate, I got an error that all fields with type numeric (Integer, Float, Long) automatically convert to 0 instead of null.

How can I keep the value `null`?.

Now, I'm using the Optional<Integer> (java.util.Optional) to workaround with this problem.

But I feel not comfortable with the `Optional` because I need to check too much isPresent() and get() with Optional.

========

I used the cmd mvn quarkus:dev in local testing=> It returns null => OK

When I deployed the code to the system (GraalVM) => It returns '0'

Comment: Does using Integer instead of Optional<Integer> , not give you null?

Comment: Hi @JCompetence, the Integer gives me 0 - cause I need the value `null`.

Comment: Could you add your Panache entity (source code) to the question? Are you sure you are using numeric objects (e.g. Integer) instead of primitive types (e.g. int)?

Comment: Yep, I used the numeric objects. The entity class extends from PanacheEntityBase.

Comment: Sorry, but the source code is too large to be made public. I will try to generate a demo version soon.

Comment: One more information: 
I used the cmd mvn quarkus:dev in local testing=> It returns null => OK
When I deployed the code to the system (GraalVM) => It returns '0'